# How can I convert set to list in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have the data like this:

```
name SF
a   {1,23,4,5}
b   {1,3,43,5}
c   {1,23,24,5}
d   {1,23,54,15}
```

I want to let the SF `set` to `list`
what I expect output is:

```
name SF
a   [1,23,4,5]
b   [1,3,43,5]
c   [1,23,24,5]
d   [1,23,54,15]
```

So,How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `apply(set)` and `apply(list)` to convert the data type back and forth:

```
df.SF = df.SF.apply(list)
print(df)

#  name               SF
#0    a    [1, 4, 5, 23]
#1    b    [1, 3, 5, 43]
#2    c   [24, 1, 5, 23]
#3    d  [1, 23, 54, 15]

df.SF = df.SF.apply(set)
print(df)

#  name               SF
#0    a    {1, 4, 5, 23}
#1    b    {1, 3, 5, 43}
#2    c   {24, 1, 5, 23}
#3    d  {1, 23, 54, 15}
```

Comment: Actually if my element is `str` `'{1,2,3,4}'`,How can I futher deal with this?

Comment: A simple and fast but potentially unsafe way is apply(eval).