# set to list in pandas doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists that I want to find their intersection.

```
b = set(a)& set(list_a)
b
{'118184', '907', '95828', '95957', '95977', '95983', '95984', '95985'}
```

Now I want b to be a list (instead of set) so I tries

```
b.apply(list)
```

([How can I convert set to list in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215361/how-can-i-convert-set-to-list-in-pandas))

And I'm getting the following error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-273-cfd36ffc3bfc> in <module>()
----> 1 b.apply(list)

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Thanks!

Comment: `b = list(b)` ?

Comment: Also tried and got :TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: restart IDE ;) Because it sems you overwrite `list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b=list(b) does seem to work (@jezrael comment)

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> c=[2,3,4]
>>> b=set(a) & set(c)
>>> b
{2, 3}
<class 'set'>
>>> b=list(b)
>>> b
[2, 3]
```

Comment: you are right , thanks !